# How to increase number of tics when using a logarithmic scale in gnuplot

Tags: gnuplot

I have created a 3D splot.

But I am not getting enough tic labels shown on x or y axis.

I tried to increase them with this:

```
set xtics 0.000001
set ytics 0.000001
```

This does increase the number of tic marks BUT not the associated labels.

[image: screenshot of graph axis]

Snippet of data (map.gnu):

```
0.00007430 0.00001000 155999
0.00007430 0.00001200 142552
0.00007430 0.00001440 141632
0.00007430 0.00001728 175229
0.00007430 0.00002074 198271
0.00007430 0.00002488 180482
0.00007430 0.00002986 121753
0.00007430 0.00003583 18049
0.00007430 0.00004300 46966
0.00007430 0.00005160 27892
0.00007430 0.00006192 20279
0.00007430 0.00008916 128832

0.00008916 0.00001000 126748
0.00008916 0.00001200 101393
0.00008916 0.00001440 143819
0.00008916 0.00001728 149303
0.00008916 0.00002074 190983
0.00008916 0.00002488 102433
0.00008916 0.00002986 13360
0.00008916 0.00003583 -27076
0.00008916 0.00004300 4639
0.00008916 0.00005160 5388
0.00008916 0.00006192 -33533
0.00008916 0.00007430 -146472
```

Script:

```
set terminal wxt size 1500,900
set ticslevel 0
set key off
set logscale x
set logscale y
set xlabel "x SHORT (log)"
set ylabel "y LONG (log)"
splot "map.gnu" using 1:2:3 with points palette pointsize 3 pointtype 7
```

Comment: It would be helpful if you showed some of the kind of data you are plotting and possibly the rest of the plotting script you are using.

Comment: @TomFenech As requested

Comment: I was wondering if you managed to solve this problem?

Answer (score 4):

Your command `set xtics 0.000001` would normally specify an increment of 0.000001. However when you are using logarithmic axes, the meaning of the increment changes. It becomes the *multiplicative factor* instead. So instead of the *difference* between each major tic, it is the *ratio* between them.

Without knowing the full range of your data it is impossible to suggest a good value for this but it should be a number greater than 1. The closer to 1 it is, the closer together your major tics will be.

Note that the unlabelled tic marks are the *minor* tics, which are of a higher frequency by default.